# Feature disappears when setting a buffer to a drawn feature with turf.js in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, geojson, buffer, turf

As shown in the code posted below, I am using `turf.js` to buffer a geometry.
The code below shows the steps I took to do the geometry buffering.
In the following step:

```
    const asOLGeom = geojsonFormat.readGeometry(buffered.geometry);
```

I convert the buffered geometry from `turf` geometry to `Open Layers` geometry.

And in the following step:

```
    this.#digitizedGeomAsFeature.setGeometry(asOLGeom);
```

I set the buffered geometry to `digitizedGeomAsFeature`

At run time, when the i digitize a polygon, and as the `evtListenerOnDrawEnd` is invoked, nothing gets displayed on the map, dispite, when i digitize a polygon i can see the vertices,
but once the polygon is closed, hence, `evtListenerOnDrawEnd** is invoked, everything disappear

**evtListenerOnDrawEnd**

```
this.#digitizedGeomAsFeature = evt.feature;
this.#modifyEvtNullifierFeature = evt.feature; //<===the feature that will be buffered
const modifyEvtNullifierAsGeom = this.#modifyEvtNullifierFeature.getGeometry();
const geojsonFormat = new GeoJSON();
const geosonGeometry = geojsonFormat.writeGeometryObject(modifyEvtNullifierAsGeom);
let buffered = turf.buffer(geosonGeometry, .02, {units: 'kilometers'});
buffered = turf.toWgs84(buffered);
const asOLGeom = geojsonFormat.readGeometry(buffered.geometry);

// set digitized features' properties
this.#digitizedGeomAsFeature.set(DigitizePolygonConstants.CONST_DIGITIZED_FEATURE_PROPERTY_WKT.description, wktRepr);
this.#digitizedGeomAsFeature.set(DigitizePolygonConstants.CONST_DIGITIZED_FEATURE_PROPERTY_GEOJSON.description, this.#geoJSONRepr);
this.#digitizedGeomAsFeature.set(DigitizePolygonConstants.CONST_DIGITIZED_FEATURE_PROPERTY_EPSG.description, this.#epsgCode);
this.#digitizedGeomAsFeature.setGeometry(asOLGeom);
```

**Update**

I also tried `buffered = turf.toMercato(buffered);` but still does not solve the problem.

Comment: What is the projection of your view?

Comment: Side note: text without capitals is very hard to read. Please use capitals in the future.

Comment: @TomazicM how can i know it please?

Comment: @TomazicM i modified the text by capitalizing the words

Comment: As for the projection of the map view, it is set by `projection` option (see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html). If projection is not set, then default projection is Spherical Mercator `'EPSG:3857'`. So what is projection of the view used in the map?

Comment: @TomazicM thanks, it is not explicitly set, so i think the projection is the defualt. is that piece of info helpful

Comment: Yes, it is helpful.

Comment: @TomazicM please have a look at the update section added to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments it's clear that map view projection is the default `EPSG:3857`. Since GeoJSON has coordinates in `EPSG:4326`, this means that projection has to be transformed when converting OL features to GeoJSON objects and also in the other direction.

`ol.format.GeoJSON` methods `.writeFeatureObject` and .`readFeature` have options `dataProjection` and `featureProjection` just for that (see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_GeoJSON-GeoJSON.html).

So code for adding buffer to drawn feature could look something like this (plain JS):

```
const geoJSONFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();

function drawEnd(e) {
  var drawnFeature = e.feature;
  const geoJSON = geoJSONFormat.writeFeatureObject(drawnFeature, {
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
    dataProjection:'EPSG:4326'
  });
  const buffered = turf.buffer(geoJSON, 0.02, {units: 'kilometers'});
  const bufferedFeature = geoJSONFormat.readFeature(buffered, {
    dataProjection:'EPSG:4326',
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
  });
  drawnFeature.setGeometry(bufferedFeature.getGeometry());
}
```

Comment: thanks for your effort and time you exerted. would you please have a look at the `2nd update` section posted above to my question

Comment: If answer helped you solve you problem, it's customary on GIS SE site to mark it as accepted, to let others with similar problems know that problem was resolved. If you have a new/additional question, please post it as a separate question.

Comment: yes, but as indicated in `2nd update` section, point 2, the geometry is still un-buffered. i do not know is it due to the code with turf api, or the way the geometry is set to be displayed on the map

Comment: Your code does not reflect code in my answer. You have some added statements like `let geomInMercator = turf.toMercator(geosonGeometry);` and `let bufferedInWgs84 = turf.toWgs84(buffered);` which make no sense. You cannot use turf methods on geometry in Mercator projection.

Comment: One question per question please. If you will use my code, it will work. If you have new/additional question, post it as separate question.

Comment: but unfortunately, still the geometry that should have been buffered, not visible on the map. i do not know whether it is placed somewhere else on the map, or never on the map at all. can you help me in this regard please?

Comment: i posted a question in stackoverflow, would you please have a look at it:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78251211/projection-and-epsg-mismatch-when-buffer-a-geometry

Comment: I don't answer questions there. If you post it on GIS SE site, I'll have a look.

Comment: In what is Mike's answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78251211/projection-and-epsg-mismatch-when-buffering-a-geometry different than mine above? It's exactly the same.